# Equivalent of $.param in angular or pure JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building a page state manager that syncs with objects in the URL and can push changes down or up.

The angular project does not include jQuery so I need to find the equivalent of `$.param()` in order to push changes from the scope up to the URL. I've seen this:

```
        function param(object){
            return Object.keys(object).map(function(k) {
                return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(object[k])
            }).join('&');
        }
```

But it only seems to go one level and fails in the following case:

```
var test = { state : { globals: {test: true, account: 5}}}
// returns "state=%5Bobject%20Object%5D"
```

Does angular have something built in I can use instead or is there another pure JS solution I can plug in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modifying the URL manually, you should make use of Angular's [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service. This will handle all the intricacies of manipulating the URL in an Angular application for you.

Furthermore, to include an object in a URL, you'd need to explicitly serialize it somehow. jQuery uses JSON, which makes sense here. Therefore, to set the `state` param in the URL, you'd use the following method:

```
$location.search('state', JSON.stringify({ globals: { test: true, account: 5 }}));
```

Comment: Cool! I knew you could use $location to search for params but didn't realize you could set them the same way.

Comment: Will this still set the state if it didn't already exist in the URL?

Comment: @Evan Yes, yes it will.

Comment: This is getting returned from $location.url() afterwards...isn't ths incorrect? '/test?state=%5Bobject%20Object%5D' same problem no?

Comment: @Evan You're right—I thought Angular would automatically serialize objects like jQuery does, but it turns out I was incorrect. I've updated my answer to include the explicit JSON encoding.